# Password protect an application

Tags: windows-7, security, passwords, microsoft-outlook-2013

At our office we each have an Outlook account. When you open Outlook, it automatically shows the inbox of the currently logged on user. Is there a way to make Windows ask for the users password again when trying to start Outlook?

I need this for my colleague at the front desk. She uses several applications that are only available on her pc, with her account (because of settings in AppData). These applications are used for control of the front barrier, security cameras,... When she's not around someone else takes over these tasks on her pc, with her account.

The problem with this is that anyone who does this, can open up her inbox. I know there are applications that I can use for this, but I prefer to use Windows settings or even a script.

Comment: Why don't you get the user to use OWA rather than Outlook? When she's away she can sign out of OWA and the mailbox will be inaccessible but her Windows account will still be usable as normal...

Comment: Because of the same reason for a lot of things, company policy. Every pc has to have Outlook installed to make switching pc's between users as fast as possible when needed.

Comment: There are a couple of options: http://www.msoutlook.info/question/795. Read the caveats, though... what you're asking is very difficult to solve. From a security POV you shouldn't let users "share" an account. Outlook is doing what it's been asked to do - manage email - and now you're trying to get it to do something it's not designed to do. You can password protect the a PST file - but once it's been opened then Outlook will, as expected, keep it open. If you genuinely need to have a shared account and prevent access to an Outlook mailbox then using Outlook is not the best solution.

Comment: "When you open Outlook, it automatically shows the inbox of the currently logged on user." - This is because your exchange server authentication is the same as your domain authentication. "Is there a way to make Windows ask for the users password again when trying to start Outlook?" - don't use Exchange Server and don't tell Outlook to save the password, the user can indicate they want to save the password, so this is a poor solution. "When she's not around someone else takes over these tasks on her pc with her account" - Have this person lock the workstation or stop using domain authenication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't protect a Windows application with a script, and there isn't either any native option that allows it, so that leaves three options:

## Option 1: password-protecting the `.pst` file

As **@Big Chris** said, you can configure Outlook to ask you for the email account's `.pst` file (where all the mails are saved).

[**Here's**](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Set-a-password-to-help-protect-your-Outlook-information-f60fb0e7-f0ad-4d7c-858b-9619d1b9f0b6) how you can do it if you're using Office 2007/2010, and [**here's**](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Set-a-password-to-help-protect-your-Outlook-information-e8cbb416-256b-4a39-8633-303bf3c70b08) the same for Office 2013 (and suppose that 2016 too).

This **can be cracked** with some effort, but will prevent the curious ones from enter where they shouldn't, so I think it'll do the job for what you want.

An alternative to this is to make Outlook to ask for your mail account's password every time you log in, but this will only avoid mail being sent/gathered, while anyone will be able to see already downloaded emails.

## Option 2: storing the `.pst`/`.ost` file in a pendrive, or encrypting it with BitLocker

You could set the saving path for the `.pst`/`.ost` file(s) for the email account in a pendrive, or protected by BitLocker, so Outlook will only work when a pendrive is connected to the computer.

Of course, your colleague will have to unplug the pendrive when she's not going to use the PC.

## Option 3: third-party program

As you mentioned, there are many programs out there which allow you to protect with a password any program in your computer, like [**Empathy**](http://migeel.sk/projects/empathy/), among others; but this will probably require admin privilleges, something which may not be accessible from your office's computers.

Comment: I used option 1 to make Outlook ask for the password. To prevent other users from starting Outlook without logging in but still reading the cached emails, I turned of email caching. This can be done in the same settings. Thanks!